# Failed to build node app on Dokku running as a Docker image on Macos

Tags: node.js, macos, docker, dokku

I've followed the steps from original documentation to deploy a Docker image of Dokku on Macos:

```
docker run \
    --env DOKKU_HOSTNAME=dokku.me \
    --name dokku \
    --publish 3022:22 \
    --publish 8080:80 \
    --publish 8443:443 \
    --volume /var/lib/dokku:/mnt/dokku \
    --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    dokku/dokku:latest
```

Source: https://hub.docker.com/r/dokku/dokku

Then I've initialized the ssh-keys within the container, and made an alias for the hostname `dokku.me` as advised. Now I can connect to the Dokku container and run commands on it, like creating a new application:

```
dokku apps:create node-test
dokku git:initialize node-test
```

I've added a new remote to my node project and tried to push:

```
git remote add dokku dokku@dokku.me:node-test
```

But pushing fails with an error that I don't understand completely:

```
➜  node-test git:(node-test) git push dokku master
Enumerating objects: 27, done.
Counting objects: 100% (27/27), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
Writing objects: 100% (27/27), 2.95 KiB | 301.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 27 (delta 4), reused 3 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
-----> Cleaning up...
-----> Building node-test from herokuish
-----> Setting config vars
       CURL_CONNECT_TIMEOUT:  90
-----> Setting config vars
       CURL_TIMEOUT:  600
-----> Adding BUILD_ENV to build environment...
       BUILD_ENV added successfully
remote: Error response from daemon: Mounts denied:
remote: The path /home/dokku/node-test/cache is not shared from the host and is not known to Docker.
remote: You can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> Resources -> File Sharing.
remote: See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac for more info.
remote: Error: failed to start containers: c1ab941dcf71650f99c3199546277ec333463a09695d0dcf1cac755d3ec7bacf
remote: You cannot attach to a stopped container, start it first
remote: 2022/01/27 15:48:15 exit status 1
To dokku.me:node-test
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'dokku.me:node-test'
```

From Docker Desktop, I've updated the file sharing options and added `/var/lib/dokku`, after I've created this folder in my Mac's filesystem.

```
➜  node-test git:(node-test) ls -al /var/lib/dokku
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel   64 Jan 27 14:22 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root  wheel  128 Jan 27 14:22 ..
```

I suspect it has something to do with the mounted folders in the Docker host, but I cannot figure out exactly what it is.

Macos version 12.01

Dokku version

```
root@b6df7b8bc9b0:/tmp# dokku version
dokku version 0.26.7
```

Docker version:

```
➜  node-test git:(node-test) docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Cloud integration: 1.0.12
 Version:           20.10.5
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        55c4c88
 Built:             Tue Mar  2 20:13:00 2021
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.5
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       363e9a8
  Built:            Tue Mar  2 20:15:47 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.4
  GitCommit:        05f951a3781f4f2c1911b05e61c160e9c30eaa8e
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc93
  GitCommit:        12644e614e25b05da6fd08a38ffa0cfe1903fdec
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Answer (score 0):

I've checked again the [Docker Installation Nodes](https://dokku.com/docs%7Ev0.26.7/getting-started/install/docker/) for v0.26.7 and noticed the `docker container run` has an extra parameter when compared to the [instructions from Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/r/dokku/dokku):

```
docker container create \
  --env DOKKU_HOSTNAME=dokku.me \
  --env DOKKU_HOST_ROOT=/var/lib/dokku/home/dokku \
  --name dokku \
  --publish 3022:22 \
  --publish 8080:80 \
  --publish 8443:443 \
  --volume /var/lib/dokku:/mnt/dokku \
  --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  dokku/dokku:0.26.7
```

The extra param `--env DOKKU_HOST_ROOT=/var/lib/dokku/home/dokku` seems to fix my issue.

Now pushing to Dokku doesn't throw the `Mounts denied` error anymore.